# SPList.Update() method call error and SharePoint Service Pack 3 for SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss, share

After I installed SharePoint Service Pack 3 I get the following error if I call **Update** method hanging off **SPList**. Anyone with similar issues?

Exception details:

**Exception**: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

**InnerException**: {"Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))"}

**Stacktrace**: "   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetListProps(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bMigrate)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.Update(Boolean bFromMigration)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.Update()\r\n  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SP3 update requires content database configuration task. The task was already performed. However, I had to do it again for it to work! Second time was a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This could be several things.

- I recall that one WSS3.0 system change warned of having to run a utility to update the database to be compatible with the update. I would give more information, but it is in the fog of my mind. Take a look a the service pack notes and see if there are any notes about any followup work that is required.
- The database or database logs may have run out of disk space.

Comment: I had to do  the config task twice! Thanks